# Deleting files older than x number of years or days

Tags: shell, unix, xargs

I huge uploads folder and tried to delete the old files eg. files older than 3 years or files added before a certain date but for some reason it ends up deleting both new and old files.

Here are the commands I tried so far

Command 1

```
 find /home/user/uploads -maxdepth 1 -type f ! -newermt "2018-10-14 00:00:00" -exec rm -v {} \;
```

This command removes everything ignoring the with ! -newermt  or just - newermt

Command 2

```
find /home/user/uploads -maxdepth 1 -mtime +1095 -type f -print -exec rm -i  {} \;
```

It returned no result

Command 3

```
find /home/user/uploads -type f ! -newermt "2018-10-14 00:00:00" | xargs rm
```

This returned an error "xargs: unmatched single quote  by default quotes are special to xargs unless you use the -o option "

I can't figure out what exactly is wrong with the commands.. I'm running on a CentOS system.

Comment: `find /home/user/uploads -maxdepth 1 -type f ! -newermt "2018-10-14 00:00:00"` is correct for matching only files older than `2018-10-14 00:00:00"`. You say "This command removes everything" -- were there files newer than that deleted?

Comment: yes... it removed new files that were created after this date, instead of files created before this date

Comment: OK, hold on. Let me come up with a test for you.

Comment: Make a `datetst` dir, e.g. `md datetst && cd datetst` create a file for every day of Oct. 2018, e.g `for i in {1..31}; do touch -d "2018-10-$i" file_$i; done`, Now let's `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f ! -newermt "2018-10-16" | sort` and see only files corresponding to days `1-16` are selected as not newer than `"2018-10-16"` which is right. Does you test given different results?

Comment: Yes, i got the results I wanted after testing your code.. it sorted out the files created before 2018-10-16. ! -newermt sorted files before and just -newermt sorted the files modified after..  I'm going to try this with my command and post the results..

Answer (score 0):

So after playing with the commands for a while this is the command that worked.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f ! -newermt "2018-10-16" -exec rm -v {} \;
```

These flags also helped incase you're come across this situation.

```
-maxdepth 1
```

means only files within that folder

```
-newermt
```

used for files modified on that date or after..

```
! -newermt
```

used for removing files before the said date.

I also added the -v flag so I would see the output of files been deleted.

Thanks for all the help this saved me a lot of time..